# Creating moving text in unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am looking for a way to create a text in Unity3D that looks like it slightly moves(without really changing position) like shaking text. I saw this in a game and it looks cool.

In other words I wants the text to move vertically some x values and back again to its position.

Doing this with coding not working for me, Here is what I did

```
Vector2 v = transform.position;
v += new Vector2(1f,1f);
transform.position = v;
```

not working. any suggestion?

I am not very familiar with animation in Unity, can I use animation to do this?

Comment: I think a Vector2 should only have 2 arguments(x and y). Your first transform is also spelled wrong

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: The movement of the text is not smooth

Comment: "Shaking" is a bit vague .. you could mean moving to random positions in a given range or just moving up and down quickly in one axis

Comment: for smooth movement always take `Time.deltaTme` into account: `transform.position += new Vector2 (1f, 1f) * Time.deltaTime;` ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use animation,
Animation will make the movement is smooth.

- Create a animation for your text.
- change your y at different time frame last frame make it 0. (Change y values to meet
  your requirements) play hope this will work

you can watch the following video it might help if your not familiar with animations.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_16b6Pl6cvM

Answer (score 0):

Use coroutines.

```
public Text text;

void Start(){
    StartCoroutine(ShakeText());
}

IEnumerator ShakeText(){
    RectTransform rt = text.rectTransform;
    Vector2 startPos = rt.anchoredPosition;
    for(float t = 0; t <= 1; t += Time.deltaTime * 5){
        rt.anchoredPosition = startPos + Vector2.up * t;
        yield return null;
    }
    for(float t = 0; t <= 1; t += Time.deltaTime * 5){
        rt.anchoredPosition = startPos + Vector2.up * (1 - t);
        yield return null;
    }
    rt.anchoredPosition = startPos;
}
```

This is a simple example of moving the text up and down but it can help you understanding and implementing something more complex, mixing rotation, scaling, etc.